# HBA mode - B140i vs P440ar

Tags: hp-proliant, hba

I have an HP DL360 g9 server running RHEL8.1 on a P440ar controller running in HBA mode whereby exposing my SSD's to do software RAID under mdadmin.

If I get another server with another HP DL360 g9 server with a B140i controller, will I be able to configure it in HBA mode and, if I want, remove the disks from the current g9 server and plug them into the new server to access the disks?   Is there any significant performance difference between the B140i and PR440ar in HBA mode?